# Allocating and deallocating memory c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, placement-new

I'm trying to implement an array class which can be dynamically sized and it will allocate memory without initialising values. My question is relating to how I deallocate the memory later:

Can I implement my code in this way?:

```
template<typename Type>
class Array {
    Type *values;

    Array(int size) : values(new (size * sizeof(Type)) char()) {}
    ~Array() {
        delete[] values;
    }
}
```

Or will I need something like this?:

```
template<typename Type>
class Array {
    Type *values;
    void *memory;

    Array(int size) : memory(new (size * sizeof(Type)) char()), values(memory), size(size) {}
    ~Array() {
        delete[] memory;
    }
}
```

NOTE!!!! I am aware that this will allocate memory without initialising any Type objects. This is the intended behavior of my code. Also the code above is not my complete implementation, it's only the code that will allocate and deallocate the memory because that is what I'm interested in with this question.

---

Upon further research I found that I should use `malloc()` and `free()` to do what I'm trying to do. Thank you to all answers and commenters.

Comment: Why not `memory(new Type[size])`?

Comment: FWIW, why not `vector<Type>` or at least study how it works and what it does! In the second example, you never construct any `Type` btw but you destroy `size` of them, which is surely wrong. Also, your allocation syntax looks odd, I would have expected `new char[some size here]`.

Comment: The reason I don't use memory (new Type[size]) or vector<Type> is because both instances will allocate the memory and then construct an instance for each position. I specified in my question that I don't want to create any instances of type, only allocate the memory for it.

Comment: @Dynisious I'd recommend you study the difference between `new char[42]` and `new char[42]()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Type*` to make life easier, and use `operator new` to get memory without constructing objects.

```
Type* values; //No aliasing/casting issues
Array(int size) : values((Type*)::operator new(sizeof(Type) * size)) //...
~Array() { /*clean up extant objects*/ ::operator delete(values); }
```

Then you can use placement new and explicit destructor calls to manage the elements. Also, placement new doesn't allocate memory. It constructs an object at the specified address.

Answer (score 1):

Placement new does not actually allocate any memory. It is merely syntax for calling a constructor with already-allocated memory.

In your destructor, you must manually call the destructors for each present element, then deallocate the memory in the same way it was allocated. Be *very* careful about exceptions.

You should probably use `std::allocator<T>::allocate` and `std::allocator<T>::deallocate`, but you could use `malloc/free`, `new char[]/delete[] (char*)arr`, or `::operator new/::operator delete`.

Comment: Not included in my answer: class-scope `operator new` and `operator delete` since I don't understand them.